# firebase db splice like operation

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

if I have data in my db similar to this

```
/values:
value1: somevalue1
value2: somevalue2
specialValue1 : 1
specialValue2 : 2  //to be "removed" and rest values moved
specialValue3 : 3
specialValue4 : 4
```

how can I do "array splice" like operation, to get rid of specialValue2 and move the rest, so I get:

```
value1: somevalue1
value2: somevalue2
specialValue1 : 1
specialValue2 : 3
specialValue3 : 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no splice-like operation in Firebase Realtime Database. You will have to read all the data, modify it in your application code, and write it back to the database.

In pure JavaScript the object manipulation would look like this:

```js
var input = {
  specialValue1 : 1,
  specialValue2 : 2, //to be "removed" and rest values moved
  specialValue3 : 3,
  specialValue4 : 4
};

var keys = Object.keys(input);
var offset = 0;
var output = {};
keys.forEach((key, index) => {
  if (input[key] != 2) {
    output[keys[index-offset]] = input[key];
  }
  else {
    offset = offset + 1;
  }
});
console.log(output);
```